# Authentication Required popup blocked access to my laptop

Tags: login-screen, authentication

I see this popup after reboot and it doesn't allow me to login into my laptop. Also I can't enter my password into the textbox.

[image]

Comment: Which Ubuntu version is that? Did it work before? If yes, what did you change or install any program so that it is not working anymore?

Comment: Its a newly installed OS, only few days ago. I haven't installed anything specific.

I am using ubuntu-22.10 and this issue start happening only with this version. I have also used other versions of ubuntu on this laptop but this is the first time I am facing this kind issues.

Comment: Same thing happened last month also.. and I had to reinstall the OS again to use my laptop.

I can't click on any button can't type any password.